# python: search and browse messages in the queue

Tags: python, search, queue

How one would search or browse messages stored in a `queue.Queue` instance?

Is it possible to do so without actually getting each message, checking its content, and putting it back?

Comment: What queue are you talking about?

Comment: reframe this question in the real world, how would you search for items in a bag without pulling them out and examining it to see if it met your criteria?

Comment: like on WMQ for example, you can browse without pulling the message out of the "bag"

Comment: Now that the OP's specified the type of queue, this is not a bad question (even though the answer is no)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind messing with details of the implementation, you can iterate over the internal deque object.

```
>>> import Queue
>>> q = Queue.Queue()
>>> q.put(1)
>>> q.put(2)
>>> with q.mutex:
...     for item in q.queue:
...             print item
... 
1
2
>>> q.get()
1
>>> q.get()
2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a means of doing that. The point of a queue is that you just do puts and gets on it.

If you need to search a queue, you could get the first element, save a reference to it, put it back into the queue and then do gets and puts till you get back to the first element (assuming that you only have one thread putting things into the queue).